# Merge multiple dataframes based on multiple column matching

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns, matching

I am aiming to selectively combine several dataframes into a single one in separate steps based on matches in two columns.

### Primary Dataset

```r
structure(list(OB_END_TIME = c("2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 18:00", 
"2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00"
), Weather.Category = c("Wind", "Flood", "Flood", "Wind", "Wind", 
"Wind", "Wind", "Wind", "Adhesion", "Subsidence"), SRC_ID = c(52L, 
67L, 103L, 2719L, 105L, 32L, 113L, 6704L, 117L, 
9569L), distance = c(4337.916253, 2825.720696, 2825.720696, 2397.887245, 
4513.448694, 3787.205117, 3774.967612, 4925.782405, 1178.442845, 
1748.086262), PRCP_AMT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), MEAN_WIND_DIR = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), MEAN_WIND_SPEED = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), MAX_GUST_DIR = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    MAX_GUST_SPEED = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Supporting Dataset 1

```r
structure(list(OB_END_TIME = c("2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00"
), SRC_ID = c(32L, 44L, 52L, 67L, 103L, 79L, 105L, 
117L, 113L, 30L), PRCP_AMT = c(0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2), HIGH_PRCN_LAT = c(1, 2, 44, 65, 
1, 1, 23, 43, 54.1346, 54.04502)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Supporting Dataset 2

```r
structure(list(OB_END_TIME = c("2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00"
),  SRC_ID = c(105L, 44L, 52L, 30L, 67L, 79L, 103L, 32L, 114L, 
    117L), MEAN_WIND_DIR = c(250L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 290L, 290L, 30L, 
    0L, 310L, 50L), MEAN_WIND_SPEED = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 5L, 
    8L, 17L, 0L, 1L, 24L), MAX_GUST_DIR = c(270L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 
    290L, 290L, 30L, 0L, 320L, 40L), MAX_GUST_SPEED = c(5L, 0L, 
    0L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 23L, 0L, 2L, 29L), HIGH_PRCN_LAT = c(1, 2, 44, 65, 
1, 1, 23, 43, 54.1346, 54.04502)), row.names = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), class = "data.frame")
```

### r Metadata

```r
platform        x86_64-w64-mingw32
version.string  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
```

### Prepatory Code

```r
dfX$OB_END_TIME <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(rain$OB_END_TIME, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

All of the dataframes have already had the above code run on their datatime column in order to standardise it for the comparison/matching.

### Matching Code

```r
primaryDataFrame <- merge(x = primaryDataFrame, y = supportingDataFrame1, by = c("SRC_ID", "OB_END_TIME"))
```

### Expected Result (Manually generated)

```r
structure(list(OB_END_TIME = c("2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 18:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00"
), Weather.Category = c("Wind", "Flood", "Flood", "Wind", "Wind", 
"Wind", "Wind", "Wind", "Adhesion", "Subsidence"), SRC_ID = c(67L, 
52L, 103L, 2719L, 105L, 32L, 113L, 6704L, 117L, 9569L), distance = c(4337.916253, 2825.720696, 2825.720696, 2397.887245, 4513.448694, 3787.205117, 3774.967612, 4925.782405, 1178.442845, 1748.086262), PRCP_AMT = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0.4, NA, 0.2, NA, 0.2, NA), MEAN_WIND_DIR = c(NA, 0L, 30L, NA, 250L, NA, NA, NA, 50L, NA), MEAN_WIND_SPEED = c(NA, 0L, 17L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 24L, NA), MAX_GUST_DIR = c(NA, 0L, 30L, NA, 270L, NA, NA, NA, 40L, NA), 
    MAX_GUST_SPEED = c(NA, 0L, 23L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 29L, NA
    )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Actual Result (Manually generated)

```r
structure(list(OB_END_TIME = c("2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", 
"2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00", "2006-01-01 00:00"), 
    Weather.Category = c("Flood", "Flood", "Wind", "Wind", "Adhesion"
    ), SRC_ID = c(52L, 103L, 105L, 113L, 117L), distance = c(2825.720696, 
    2825.720696, 4513.448694, 3774.967612, 1178.442845), PRCP_AMT.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PRCP_AMT.y = c(0, 
    0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2), MEAN_WIND_DIR.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MEAN_WIND_DIR.y = c(0L, 30L, 250L, NA, 50L
    ), MEAN_WIND_SPEED.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MEAN_WIND_SPEED.y = c(0L, 17L, 3L, NA, 24L), MAX_GUST_DIR.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, MAX_GUST_DIR.y = c(0L, 
    30L, 270L, NA, 40L), MAX_GUST_SPEED.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MAX_GUST_SPEED.y = c(0L, 23L, 5L, NA, 
    29L)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Problems with the results:

1) Columns that fail the match in the primary dataset are deleted.

2) The column that should be populated with the data is instead duplicated to `PRCP_AMT.x` and `PRCP_AMT.y`.

3) Unwanted columns are added to the primary dataset during the match (`HIGH_PRCN_LAT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for issue 1) you can just add `all.x = T` :

```
primaryDataFrame <- merge(x = primaryDataFrame, y = supportingDataFrame1, by = c("SRC_ID", "OB_END_TIME"), all.x = T)
```

For issue 2)  then the `merge` is happening as to be expected. You have duplicate columns because they are called the same - you should give them different names and select / rename the one you wish to keep.

You can drop a column for 3) thus:

```
primaryDataFrame <- merge(x = primaryDataFrame, y = supportingDataFrame1, by = c("SRC_ID", "OB_END_TIME"), all.x = T) %>% 
    select(-HIGH_PRCN_LAT)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution to each of the three issues!